# What laryngeal should be reconstructed in PIE word for wasp?

Tags: etymology, proto-indo-european

I encountered a contradiction between two respectful monographs.

Mallory gives the word as *h<sub>2/3</sub>u̯obhseh<sub>2</sub>* thus excluding *h<sub>1</sub>* while de Vaan gives totally opposite version, *h<sub>1</sub>u̯obhseh<sub>2</sub>* thus excluding *h<sub>2</sub>* and *h<sub>3</sub>*. I wonder who is right? What do say the primary sources?

In other words the both sources also differ similarly.

Comment: I think Mallory has more than the common 3 laryngals or at least something like "ha" in addition. He seems to represent an older tradition of the laryngal theories. And de Vaan has *(h1)uebh- 'to weave' as underlaying root.

Comment: @aorists Mallory asserts that in the root for weave there also should be h2/3

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The word for 'wasp' does not require a laryngeal:

Middle Persian *wpz*, Lat. *vespa*, Welsh *gwychi*, Old English *wæfs*, Lith. dial. *vapsà*, Russian *osá* are all compatible with *uobʰs-h₂-

The only reason to reconstruct a laryngeal is if you assume the word is derived from 'to weave' (seeing wasps as 'weavers' of their nests), but this is not evident.

The word for 'weave': The evidence for a *h₁ in this word the Mycenean future participle *e-we-pe-se-so-me-na* 'that must be woven', attested once:

> pa-we-a₂ e-we-pe-se-so-me-na  WOOL  20 'twenty woolen cloaks to be woven'

The alternative interpretation as 'to be well boiled' is highly improbable (see Beekes 1969: 67).

The evidence for *h₂/₃ is presumably the connection with Hitt. *huppai-zi* 'to blend', however this is not possible due to the fortis -*pp*- in Hittite, which implies IE *p, and the semantics are not that strong, either.

But once again, this is only relevant if wasps were seen as 'weavers', which is rather a speculative conjecture.